# How mysql works with android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

If we build an android app on android studio with php and mysql, when we build the app to install on our phone, how mysql database works although it is in our machine.

Comment: Are you seeking a tutorial?  We don't offer those here.  Please refine your question to isolate a specific issue that you have.  Please take the tour and read how to ask a question.  As it stands, your question may be closed as Off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a REST API, because MySql and PHP would be on a separate server and as I recall there are not any options available to make them connect with each other.